# Understanding Mean Square Prediction Error (MSPE)

Tags: regression, forecasting, prediction, definition, mse

I want to calculate MPSE, mean square prediction error, to compare the performance of several regression models that I developed with training data on new testing data.

Is the mean square prediction error simply calculated as the **mean** of (Predicted Values - Observed Values)^2? The observed values here are the response variable from the testing dataset.

Also, can the predicted values be obtained from the R code below?

```
predict(lm.fit, newdata=testing, interval="prediction")
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you simply take the mean of the squared errors. This is often simply called Mean Squared Error ([mse](/questions/tagged/mse) - take a look at the tag), since the P often refers to percentages, e.g. in the [mape](/questions/tagged/mape). I'd argue that "prediction" is redundant, since you should always evaluate your prediction on holdout data, anyway.

And yes, you can obtain your predictions from an `lm` object by using `predict()`. (More precisely, `predict.lm()`.) However, since the MSE is a *point* accuracy measure, you only need point predictions, not intervals, so you can go with the default parameter `interval="none"`.

Comment: But *mean squared error* can also address, for example, estimation precision of a model parameter. So the P for *prediction* in MSPE is not entirely redundant, IMHO.